# Node's console is not showing all the object properties ... is this expected behavior?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I did a

```
  console.log(myURL);
```

and did not see the extension property

```
  console.log(myURL.extension);
```

but if I log it on it's own it correctly shows the value.

found is a URL object created as such:

```
  const url = require('url');
  let myURL = new URL(test);
```

the missing property was added as such:

```
  myURL.extension = test.split('.').pop();
```

The output looks like this:

```
URL {
  href: 'https://www.imdb.com/favicon.ico',
  origin: 'https://www.imdb.com',
  protocol: 'https:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'www.imdb.com',
  hostname: 'www.imdb.com',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/favicon.ico',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: ''
}
```

Example code:

```
const url = require('url');
const test = 'https://www.imdb.com/favicon.ico';
let myURL = new URL(test);
myURL.extension = test.split('.').pop();
console.log(myURL);
```

Comment: It is impossible to tell why this is the case without knowing some context, like what `found` is. So you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: found is a URL object ... question has been updated.

Comment: [url objects](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) don't have an `extension` property...

Comment: I added the extension property to it.  It is basically the tld.

Comment: This seems bizarre to me or is it expected behavior?

Comment: You can still _use_ the `extension` property via `myURL.extension`, but one of the following symbols is causing the format of `URL` objects to be defined by the class rather than what properties it has on it: `> Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(url.URL.prototype)
[
  Symbol(special),
  Symbol(cannot-be-base),
  Symbol(cannot-have-username-password-port),
  Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom),
  Symbol(format),
  Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
]`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's `util.inspect.custom`

Comment: @Bergi I figured it was either that one or `format` but I was just showing the asker how to see them.

Comment: try using `console.log(util.inspect(obj, false, null))`

Comment: @George same problem

Comment: It is potentially a non enumerable property, if it was made with `Object.defineProperty` with `enumerable: false`

Comment: @George [nope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycuu1.png)

Comment: Clearly `myURL.extension = ...` is not defined with `enumerable: false`

Comment: please can you put the test object in your question, so I can try to replicate the issue. it is not clear what `test.split('.').pop();` means.

Comment: How do I put the test object in my question?  I posted the output.  You can create one with two lines of code like in my question.

Comment: Basically, new URL internally is not an object literal, so you can't be sure how it handles having new properties added to it. Why are you adding extension property to it anyway? Looks more like an XY problem. You could create an outer object and add your URL object and extension inside that. If you want to get more involved, you could create a new class that extends URL, but probably not...

Comment: For example, see the output of `console.log({...myURL});`, and you can see your extension property, but you also see a different output, probably because the URL getter isn't being pulled along with the ...spread object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is because the `prototype` of [`URL`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_url) defines a [`util.inspect.custom`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_custom) override. In Node.js v12.11.0 for example, it's defined like this:

```
> console.log(myURL[util.inspect.custom])

[inspect.custom](depth, opts) {
  if (this == null ||
      Object.getPrototypeOf(this[context]) !== URLContext.prototype) {
    throw new ERR_INVALID_THIS('URL');
  }

  if (typeof depth === 'number' && depth < 0)
    return this;

  const ctor = getConstructorOf(this);

  const obj = Object.create({
    constructor: ctor === null ? URL : ctor
  });

  obj.href = this.href;
  obj.origin = this.origin;
  obj.protocol = this.protocol;
  obj.username = this.username;
  obj.password = this.password;
  obj.host = this.host;
  obj.hostname = this.hostname;
  obj.port = this.port;
  obj.pathname = this.pathname;
  obj.search = this.search;
  obj.searchParams = this.searchParams;
  obj.hash = this.hash;

  if (opts.showHidden) {
    obj.cannotBeBase = this[cannotBeBase];
    obj.special = this[special];
    obj[context] = this[context];
  }

  return inspect(obj, opts);
}
```

You could override this behavior and add the `extension` property as a getter to the `URL` class's `prototype` if you *really* cared about the output format:

```
const { URL } = require('url');
const { inspect } = require('util');

Object.defineProperty(URL.prototype, 'extension', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  get() { return this.pathname.split('.').pop(); }
});

URL.prototype[inspect.custom] = function(depth, opts) {
  if (typeof depth === 'number' && depth < 0) return this;

  const keys = Object.keys(URL.prototype).filter(key => typeof this[key] !== 'function');
  const obj = Object.create({ constructor: URL });
  Object.assign(obj, ...keys.map(key => ({ [key]: this[key] })));
  return inspect(obj, opts);
};
```

and then your output format will look like this:

```
> new URL('https://www.imdb.com/favicon.ico')
URL {
  href: 'https://www.imdb.com/favicon.ico',
  origin: 'https://www.imdb.com',
  protocol: 'https:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'www.imdb.com',
  hostname: 'www.imdb.com',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/favicon.ico',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: '',
  extension: 'ico'
}
```

However, if you don't care that much then you can just accept that the output format you see is the expected behavior, and you can access the `extension` property just as you normally would on any other object.

Comment: What's the output when you just `delete myURL[util.inspect.custom];`?

Comment: @Bergi [not particularly useful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7OmE.png) (and yes I did try that before deciding to write a custom method).